# 404 Get request in laravel from src file path

Tags: html, laravel, visual-studio-code

Im trying to load an image from my /public/images folder in laravel. Im getting a 404 not found error. I know the image exists, and vscode even autocompletes the path for me.

here is the img tag:

```
<img src="/public/images/1616327614.jpg" class="im" alt="...">
```

and the file path:

[image: file path]

I have also tried variations of the img src path, for example:

```
<img src="./public/images/1616327614.jpg" class="im" alt="...">
<img src="./images/1616327614.jpg" class="im" alt="...">
```

Any advice here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do something like this,

```
<img src="{{asset('images/1616327614.jpg')}}" class="im" alt="...">
```

Or

```
<img src="{{public_path('images/1616327614.jpg')}}" class="im" alt="...">
```

Remember to always check the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-public-path